# Creating order in columns

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using the col-md-6 class in bootstrap to arrange my content into two 50% columns.

Here is a demonstration of how it looks and how I want it to look. The one on the left is how it looks and the one on the right is how I want it to look:

[image]

The titles seem to align fine, but the rest of the content does not.

Also, for some reason, the third title is lagging on the bottom instead of aligning to the fourth title (I have no idea why).

Code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <?php

    while ($query->have_posts())
    {
        $query->the_post();

        ?>

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" align="middle"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php

                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    echo '<p>';
                    the_post_thumbnail("small");
                    echo '</p>';
                }
            ?>
            </a>
            <p><br /><?php the_excerpt(); ?><p>
            <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-info">
                <h3>Free trial available?</h3>
                <p><?php the_field('free'); ?></p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <?php
    }
    ?>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: p tag is not properly closed. <p><br /><?php the_excerpt(); ?><p>

Comment: If PHP is related to the question (I don't think so), add the tag. Otherwise replace the PHP code with the resulting HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
    $i=0;
    while ($query->have_posts())
    {
        if($i%2==0)
            echo '<div class="row">';
        $query->the_post();

        ?>

        <div class="col-md-6" >
           <div style="height:600px">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" align="middle"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php

                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    echo '<p>';
                    the_post_thumbnail("small");
                    echo '</p>';
                }
            ?>
            </a>
            <p><br /><?php the_excerpt(); ?><p>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-info">
                <h3>Free trial available?</h3>
                <p><?php the_field('free'); ?></p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <?php
        if($i%2!=0)
            echo '</div>';
        $i++;
    }
    ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? I only have one col-md-6.

Comment: No, you have one for each times you run the while cycle.

Comment: Can you relate that to my code? I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: I've changed my answer. Is a little pattern you could use to paint your application.

Comment: What is the post 1 post 2 etc. referring to?

Comment: copy-paste the answer.

Comment: Thank you. That helped with the problem where one of the posts kept being out of position. It also lined the content up a bit better. However, the core of my question is lining up the content.

See: http://prntscr.com/atd54v

I want the blue box and the text to line up with each other, so that each text start in the same vertical height and each blue box start in the same vertical height.

Comment: Another example where one text is shorter, leaving the content disorganized http://prntscr.com/atd8f1

Comment: try it now, I've added a `div` with an `height` value.

Comment: That works, but how will it affect mobile/different screens? I thought about doing it myself but I wasn't sure.

Also, should I just make sure all thumbnails are the same size or should I add a similar div with height style for the image to make sure they are always equal?

Comment: it's better add images with same size (but different width). With smartphone you shouldn't have problems :)

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this:

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.content1{
  background-color:red;
}

.content2{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
​<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 content1">
 <h1> CONTENT</h1><h1>
   <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
</h1></div> 
<div class="col-md-6 content2">
  <h1> CONTENT</h1><h1>
   <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
</h1></div> 

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Am I closer? http://www.bootply.com/WRDKewHyQn

(I don't know a good place to paste code so I just pasted it there).

Comment: and you must write this code cleaner, you have some php call outside columns (between content 1 and 2)

Comment: This is what I have: http://www.bootply.com/EyC6aZUGwD

It's still not working. The content is not matching up to the titles etc.

Comment: Also, this code seems to put the title on the left, the picture on the right and then the excerpt on the left again.

Comment: Can you provide link of site?

Comment: there is no, <div class="row"> ,also there is no content in content1 and content2, instead of that , you put that content in col-md12, and that is your problem.
you see: http://pokit.org/get/?ccd0139f8a654f658c5efbe6f044580f.jpg

Comment: After reverting to my original code, there is a row.

http://prntscr.com/atcl86

Also the columns work fine, but the content INSIDE the columns doesn't align vertically. That's what I want (see the pictures in the original question).

Comment: please ad row class to first and second col-md6 than close div, then open new row, for 3 and 4, then close

Comment: That doesn't do it at all. http://pastebin.com/dBzLH0mg

I'm not sure we are speaking about the same thing.

You see the "get_title" etc, that's the title of my post. The if function is getting the thumbnail and the excerpt and the warning box are extra information to my post preview.

What your suggestions are doing, is they are splitting the content of my post (title, excerpt, etc.) into several different columns. That's not what I want to do. I don't want my title on the left and my picture on the right. I just want my content to line up vertically.

Comment: My solution is this : http://www.bootply.com/wcXnGOCMRu

Simple: they put first and second column i one row, and third and fourth in another, so they will align properly

Comment: Okay but you have two pieces of content.

Comment: I only have ONE (the entire code with all my post information). The next piece of content will be the next post.

Comment: Can you build that example by having your H1 line up with H1 on the other content and the p line up with the p of the other content, despite having different lengths?

Comment: Or, I hate to ask, but can you just build my code the way you say it should work and then we'll see if it will?

Comment: Ok , try this, i'm not sure for php calls, but im lookin on picture from your first post and paste this code: http://www.bootply.com/NUAFtrkFOi